# Convert this array of arrays into array of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have this array of arrays in python.

```
staff = [
            ['staff1', '2/18/1998', 21.63],
            ['staff2', '7/7/1999',  15.87],
            ['staff3', '8/26/2004', 123.46],
        ]
```

I have this array which specify the columns.

```
out_columns = ['Name','Date','Profit']
```

Based on these 2 arrays, I would like to convert them into an array of dictionaries that look like this;

```
dict_arr = [
                {"Name":"staff1",
                 "Date":"2/18/1998",
                 "Profit":21.63
                 },
                {"Name": "staff2",
                 "Date": "7/7/1999",
                 "Profit": 15.87
                 },
                {"Name": "staff3",
                 "Date": "8/26/2004",
                 "Profit": 123.46
                 },
]
```

I am using python v3.6

Comment: SO is not a free coding site. Please demonstrate effort to solve yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function :

```
nl = []
for zz in staff:
    aa = {}
    for key,val in zip(out_columns,zz):
        aa[key]= val
    nl.append( aa )
print(nl) # [{'Name': 'staff1', 'Date': '2/18/1998', 'Profit': 21.63} , ... ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was at a loss over how to even start. I will study your answer carefully.